# PHP/FORM problem

Tags: php, mysql, forms, form-submit

I'm new to programming so please bear with me...I'm using MySQL/PHP to create an application where part of it allows users to select a location and room from two drop down menus.  There are three tables, room, location and room_location.  I have created forms that allow user to add a room to room table and a form to allow them to add a location to location table - these both work fine as the input is just a text field and the user can submit any text they like.  My problem is with the third form/table (dropdown_form.php)- this table has three fields, id | room_name | location_name.

What I am trying to achieve with the room_location table is this: 
The user will get a webpage that has a dropdown menu for selecting a location_name (which is derived from the location table) and another dropdown menu for selecting the room_name (which is derived from the room table). After selecting from both dropdowns the user will submit this combination of room and location and a new entry will be added to the room_location table in the database.

example of room_location table

ID  |  location_name  | room_name
1   |  Hospital1      | room1

2   |  Hospital1      | room2

3   |  Hospital1      | room3

4   |  Hospital2      | room1

5   |  Hospital2      | room2
etc

So far I've got the form for this to display both of the dropdown menus but when I select and submit I get an error saying "Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' " I included some echo statements for testing purposes to see what is happening, I'm now getting:

Location and Room name entered was

Array ( [select_location] => [select_room] => )

Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
(duplicate entry appears to be NULL? so don't think anything is actually being passed to process.php)

It appears that there is something wrong (I think) with the selects that are supposed to be passing the data to process.php which is handling the $_POST statements.  I've included a copy of my code, any help at all with this would be greatly appreciated.

dropdown_form.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Testing Dropdown form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
        //make connection to the database
        mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "password") or die ('Database connection ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db ("my_database");
?>

<fieldset style="width:30%" align="center"><legend><b>Add New Location/Room Combination</b></legend>
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> 
        <b> Location Name: </b> 
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> 
        <b> Room Name: </b> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <!-- create form to submit data process.php -->
        <form name="room_location_form" action="process.php" method="post">
        <select name="select_location">         

        <?php
        //create and run a query that selects all the locations to create an options list
        $loc_query = "SELECT location_name FROM location ORDER BY location_name";
        $loc_result = mysql_query($loc_query);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loc_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
        {
        echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[location_name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td>        
        <?php
        //create and run a query that selects all the rooms to create an options list
        $room_query = "SELECT room_name FROM room_name ORDER BY room_name";
        $room_result = mysql_query($room_query);
        ?>

        <select name="select_room">

        <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($room_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            {
            echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[room_name]</option>";
            }
        ?>  
        </select>

    </td>

    <!--Add a submit button -->
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Location/Room">
    </td>

</tr>

</form>
</table>
</fieldset>

<br>
<br>
<hr width=50%>
<br>
 <table border=1 align=center cellspacing=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Location Name</th>
        <th>Room Name</th>
    </tr>

<?php

//build query to display a list of all current locations and rooms
 $query = mysql_query("select * from room_location ORDER BY location_name, room_name"); 

  //return the array and loop through each row
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $location_name = $row['location_name'];
  $room_name = $row['room_name'];

 ?>

    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $location_name;?></th>
        <th><?php echo $room_name;?></th>
    </tr>

<?php }  //this ends the loop   
?>
```

process.php

```
<?php
//make connection
$conn = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "password"); 
if (!$conn) 
    {
    die ('Database connection ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
    }
$db = mysql_select_db ("my_database");

//Add new Location and Room Name combination - sent from form
$sql="INSERT INTO room_location (location_name, room_name) VALUES (('$_POST[select_location]'), ('$_POST[select_room]'))"; 
    echo "Location and Room name entered was ", $_POST['select_location'], " & ", $_POST['select_room']; 
?>
<br> <!-- Line break just to see what is being output when testing -->
<?php
print_r($_POST);  //added for testing purposes to see what is being POSTed
?>
<br> <!-- Line break just to see what is being output when testing -->
<?php
if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
    {
    die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Location and Room name entered was ", $_POST['select_location'], " & ", $_POST['select_room']; 

mysql_close($conn)
 ?>
```

****UPDATES MADE AS SUGGESTED********* 
Thanks for the suggestions so far, I;ve made some progess thanks to you all. Using code below I now get select_location outputting as location_id and select_room outputting as room_name_id instead of the location_name and room_name - any ideas what I'm doing wrong guys?

dropdown_form.php

```
    <?php
    //make connection to the database
            mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "password") or die ('Database connection ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db ("my_database");
    ?>

    <fieldset style="width:30%" align="center"><legend><b>Add New Location/Room Combination</b></legend>
    <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> 
            <b> Location Name: </b> 
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> 
            <b> Room Name: </b> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <!-- create form to submit data process.php -->
            <form name="room_location_form" action="process.php" method="post">
            <select name="select_location">         

            <?php
            //create and run a query that selects all the locations to create an options list
            $loc_query = "SELECT location_id,location_name FROM location ORDER BY location_name";
            $loc_result = mysql_query($loc_query);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loc_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            {
            echo "<option value=\"".$row['location_id']."\">".$row['location_name']."</option>\n";
            }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td>        
            <?php
            //create and run a query that selects all the rooms to create an options list
            $room_query = "SELECT room_name_id,room_name FROM room_name ORDER BY room_name";
            $room_result = mysql_query($room_query);
            ?>

            <select name="select_room">

            <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($room_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
                {
                echo "<option value=\"".$row['room_name_id']."\">".$row['room_name']."</option>\n";
                        }
            ?>  
            </select>

        </td> 

        <!--Add a submit button -->
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Location/Room">
        </td>

    </tr>

    </form>
    </table>
    </fieldset>

    <br>
    <br>
    <hr width=50%>
    <br>
     <table border=1 align=center cellspacing=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Location Name</th>
            <th>Room Name</th>
        </tr>

    <?php

    //build query to display a list of all current locations and rooms
     $query = mysql_query("select * from room_location ORDER BY location_name, room_name"); 

      //return the array and loop through each row
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      $location_name = $row['location_name'];
      $room_name = $row['room_name'];

     ?>

        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $location_name;?></th>
            <th><?php echo $room_name;?></th>
        </tr>

    <?php }  //this ends the loop   
    ?>
```

process.php

```
    <?php
    //make connection
    $conn = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "password"); 
    if (!$conn) 
        {
        die ('Database connection ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    $db = mysql_select_db ("my_database");

        //Add new Location and Room Name combination - sent from form
        $sql="INSERT INTO room_location (location_name, room_name) VALUES (('".$_POST['select_location']."'), ('".$_POST['select_room']."'))"; 

    ?>
    <br> <!-- Line break just to see what is being output when testing -->
    <?php
    print_r($_POST);  //added for testing purposes to see what is being POSTed
    ?>
    <br> <!-- Line break just to see what is being output when testing -->
    <?php
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
        {
        die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    echo "Location and Room name entered was ", [$_POST['select_location']], " & ", $_POST['select_room']; 

    mysql_close($conn)
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

besides what others have said,

in **dropdown_form.php** on your SELECTS, to get the dropdowns your not retrieving an id for the id value in the form.

```
SELECT location_name FROM location ORDER BY location
make it 
SELECT id,location_name FROM location ORDER BY location desc
```

then you can access it like:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['location_name']."</option>\n";
```

notice i also formatted it correctly

*do the same with the second select..*.

On inserting the new row into the database make sure that the id is the primary key and auto increments.
**the query:**

```
$sql='INSERT INTO room_location (`id`,`location_name`, `room_name`) VALUES ("","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select_location']).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select_room']).'")';
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help so far.
You were absolutely correct that the main issue was I wasn't SELECTing any id values, I've added that but unfortunately the query didn't work it threw a sytax error on that line - using a combination of your SELECT statement and @Lamoni Lamonis query I am now able to get a bit further, I get a value returned for select_room and select_location but it is its id number rather than the name which is what I need (insert statement fails since it needs the name not the id) - hope this makes sense.  I'll post my full updated code again as a seperate comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just making note because I'm assuming you removed the sanitizing for quick purposes on this post, but make sure you are sanitizing your `$_POST` variables against SQL Injection.

With that said, try replacing your query with this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO room_location (location_name, room_name) VALUES (('".$_POST['select_location']."'), ('".$_POST['select_room']."'))";
```

EDIT:

Seems I am a bit late on this, as Blender has already noted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting auto increment to your id field in database

Comment: Hi, yes the location_room_id is auto increment and is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked this myself...not the most elegant solution but it works :D Thanks for the pointers.

*UPDATE to process.php *****

```
<?php
    //This section retrieves the room name selected on dropdown_form.php page
    $room_id = $_POST['select_room']; //temp variable to hold room_name_id
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT room_name FROM room_name WHERE room_name_id = $room_id");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
      {
       $room_name = $row['room_name'];
      }

    //This section retrieves the location name selected on add_room_location_form.php page
    $location_id = $_POST['select_location']; //temp variable to hold location_name_id
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT location_name FROM location WHERE location_id = $location_id");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
      {
      $location_name = $row['location_name'];
          }

    //Insert room & location data held in $location_name & $room_name into room_location table
    $sql="INSERT INTO room_location (location_name, room_name) VALUES (('$location_name'), ('$room_name'))"; 
    echo "Location and Room name entered was ", $location_name, " & ", $room_name;  

    //I tried using this INSERT below but it inserts the array indexes instead of elements to location_name, room_name.
    //$sql="INSERT INTO room_location (location_name, room_name) VALUES (('".$_POST['select_location']."'), ('".$_POST['select_room']."'))";    
?>
```